# subtract Object value into array is not correct

Tags: javascript

l am trying to sum total price from array object then add the total price outside that array.

example :

```
[
  {
    "addons": [
      {
        "title": "خبز بعجين",
        "price": 0.1,
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "title": "لحم بعجين ",
        "price": 2,
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "title": "ببسي بارد",
        "price": 55,
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "title": "كولا ",
        "price": 4,
        "selected": true
      }
    ],
    "Totaladdons": 61.1, // < total price of array above . 
    "price" : 300  // < sum Totaladdons with this object price . 
  }
```

]

```
  sum(data) {
    let totalPrice = 0;
    let currency: any

    currency = this.items_local[data.index].addons.map(curr => parseFloat(curr.price)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    console.log(currency);
    this.items_local[data.index].Totaladdons = Number(currency);
    if (this.items_local[data.index].Totaladdons) {
      totalPrice = Number(this.items_local[data.index].Totaladdons) + Number(this.items_local[data.index].price)
      this.items_local[data.index].price = totalPrice.toFixed(2)

    }
  }
```

Minus method to remove element array object then resuming total price

```
 minus(data) {

    if (this.items_local[data.index].addons.length > 0) {
      for (var i = this.items_local[data.index].addons.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (this.items_local[data.index].addons[i].title === data.addon.title) {
          this.items_local[data.index].addons.splice([i], 1);

           // here l am try to resuming the price of array object
          currency = this.items_local[data.index].addons.map(curr => parseFloat(curr.price)).reduce((a, b,) => a - b, 0);
          console.log(currency);

            if (this.items_local[data.index].Totaladdons) {
              this.items_local[data.index].Totaladdons = Number(currency);
              totalPrice = Number(this.items_local[data.index].price) - Number(this.items_local[data.index].Totaladdons)
              this.items_local[data.index].price = totalPrice.toFixed(2)
            }
        }
      }

    }

  }
```

The problem is when l click on the minus method he is not giving me the correct total number.

Comment: you have some code here and your attempt, which is great. What's missing is the sample data. Like an object for the existing order (is that the one you posted?) and what the `data` argument in `sum(data)` and `minus(data)` look like

Comment: @Kinglish . Thank you for your comment.  Actually, I tried to make my code in the question very short. The main code is too much longer. All data arguments are fine. Nothing is missing. But the problem is l am not getting the correct sum. Maybe the for loop is affected on sum? because it's inside for loop?

Comment: thats the thing. You are very close to having code that can be reproduced in a snippet and this stuff is so much easier to troubleshoot when one can run it and adjust. So, you'll probably get more help if you set this up as a working snippet (I think all we need is a sample of the original data, and then what the data argument for the functions are).

Comment: @Kinglish . Okay let me prepare my code on stackblitz

Comment: @Kinglish . You can get my snippet code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-checkbox-list-klanto?file=pages/list/list.component.ts

Comment: Please post the [mcve] here. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable, you don't need stackblitz.com.

Comment: I can look later. Initially, you dont' need ionChange($event) - you're using ngModel which will keep track of what is checked and what isn't. I will look deeper later